# R: Replacing part of data frame

Tags: r, replace

I want to replace values in following data frame

```
x <- letters[1:10]
y <- 1:10
z <- 100:109
df <- data.frame(x,y,z)
```

with this sub data frame

```
repl <- data.frame(x = c('c', 'e'), y = c(13,15))
```

so that column `y` gets modified only when `x` column fits the replacement data frame. And I don't want to take care of orders of values in column `x`. If these are ordered well it is easy.

```
df[df$x %in% repl$x, c('x','y')] <- repl
```

But what to do if the replacing data frame is

```
repl <- data.frame(x = c('e', 'c'), y = c(15,13))
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `match` instead of %in%:

```
    repl <- data.frame(x = c('c', 'e'), y = c(13,15))
df[match(repl$x,df$x),'y'] <-repl$y
> df
   x  y   z
1  a  1 100
2  b  2 101
3  c 13 102
4  d  4 103
5  e 15 104
6  f  6 105
7  g  7 106
8  h  8 107
9  i  9 108
10 j 10 109
```

This is the result with the second formulation:

```
 repl <- data.frame(x = c('e', 'c'), y = c(15,13))
 df[match(repl$x,df$x),'y'] <-repl$y
> df
   x  y   z
1  a  1 100
2  b  2 101
3  c 13 102
4  d  4 103
5  e 15 104
6  f  6 105
7  g  7 106
8  h  8 107
9  i  9 108
10 j 10 109
```